# pg_rewind: ERROR: could not fetch remote file "global/pg_control": ERROR: permission denied

Tags: postgresql-replication

I came across this error notice when trying to execute `pg_rewind` through `repmgr`'s old primary demotion to standby after recovery. (the old standby @192.168.1.2 has already executed `repmgr standby promote`)

`postgres` version=15.4 `repmgr` version=5.4dev and the command to execute such process and the following feedback are these:

```
repmgr node rejoin --force-rewind -d 'host=192.168.1.2 port=5432 user=rep dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=5'
NOTICE: rejoin target is node "yzx2" (ID: 2)
NOTICE: pg_rewind execution required for this node to attach to rejoin target node 2
DETAIL: rejoin target server's timeline 2 forked off current database system timeline 1 before current recovery point 0/81C6D80
NOTICE: executing pg_rewind
DETAIL: pg_rewind command is "/usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_rewind -D '/pgdata' --source-server='host=192.168.1.2 port=5432 user=rep dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=5'"
ERROR: pg_rewind execution failed
DETAIL: pg_rewind: error: could not fetch remote file "global/pg_control": ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_read_binary_file
```

Actually I have grant function pg_read_binary_file's execution right to the user rep, and here are the setup for this role:

```
CREATE EXTENSION repmgr;
 GRANT pg_checkpoint TO rep;
 GRANT pg_read_all_stats TO rep;
GRANT EXECUTE ON function pg_catalog.pg_ls_dir(text, boolean, boolean) TO rep;
GRANT EXECUTE ON function pg_catalog.pg_stat_file(text, boolean) TO rep;
GRANT EXECUTE ON function pg_catalog.pg_read_binary_file(text) TO rep;
GRANT EXECUTE ON function pg_catalog.pg_read_binary_file(text, bigint, bigint, boolean) TO rep;
```

I re-grant the right again using `GRANT EXECUTE ON function pg_read_binary_file(text) TO rep;`, and it made no difference. It is not that the user `rep` does not have the right to execute the function, but that the function has no right to `fetch remote file "global/pg_control"`? BTW, I did not give ssh right to access postgres Linux account on another server for security reasons.